# eclipse server application doesn't support arabic chars

Tags: mysql, eclipse, arabic

i am building a server application using eclipse , and the client is android application

when i used just Java application i can read arabic chars from mysql and can print it correctly to eclipse ,but on server application i can't , the results are question marks like this `?????`

i am trying to print the results on eclipse not on android

my connect to database is :

```
String unicode = "?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8";
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ams-competation" + unicode,
                    username, password);
```

don't care about android , i am asking how to read and print arabic chars on eclipse server application

## EDIT

seems like my problem is from the eclipse not from the connection because when i tried this `System.out.println("روما");` , i got question marks 
and when i tried to check that question marks with this statements

```
if(q.getFirstChoice().equals("بيرلو"))
                System.out.println("dddd");
```

the results was `dddd` , so i can read it correctly from mysql , but my problem on printing the results

Comment: help please, i need help

Comment: thank you all , i solve it myself, and this is the solution http://www.mobilefish.com/developer/eclipse/eclipse_quickguide_display_unicode_in_console.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `system.out` do not support `UtF-8` characters so you should be using following code

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
out.println(“some-utf8-string”);
```

you can also see the [reference](http://poeticcode.wordpress.com/2009/01/19/systemout-and-utf8/).

**Edited**:
Other workaround is

- In the Run Configuration, Arguments tab, I added "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" to the VM arguments
- In the Run configuration, Common tab, I set the Console Encoding to UTF-8

Comment: your statements doesn't print any thing , and System.out prints utf-8 chars on java applications

Comment: why it doesn't print any thing ?

Comment: yes that was the soultion , and i found it already , anyway really thank you for help , i accept your answer